# Creating a SOAP API in ASP.NET that sends out data to a separate instance of the same application

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, soap

I apologize for my rather vague question, but I am at a bit of a loss. The documentation for MSDN API functionality is very confusing and convoluted to say the least, and I have been tasked to figure out a way to get the desired functionality mentioned in the title.

Basically, my intent is to create an API using SOAP that sends out data to a separate instance of the same application, with the intent of *synchronizing their databases*. It is important that this data is **sent** by the primary database, and not **requested** by the receiving end, as that could create a security hole in the architecture if our primary database was that open.

I don't want to simply ask for code, but a very lightweight example of how this could be achieved on both ends would be extremely helpful. I don't really have anything significant to show other than a very simple Test Service.

Comment: What kind of application is this? ASP.NET? If so, then what do you mean by "a separate instance of the same application"? Also, why does the API need to be created in ASP.NET? Which version of .NET are you using?

Comment: It's a web application that allows users to issue and take assessments. There is an on-premise version of the app that administrators would use, and a cloud version that users would use to fill out assessments. We are using .NET version 4.5.

Comment: You should create a windows service and run it in both environments. The two services can host a WCF service that can be used to sync.

Answer (score 0):

Is the problem that those other systems cannot initiate sessions due to network security?  The challenge is that Soap services are made to receive a request.  In order to do what you want, the client systems will have to have a soap service or some other kind of service that yours can call too.  Then your service can synchronize to at least tell them to call your service.  There are lot's of ways to approach this with the kind of architecture I mentioned.